# How can I deploy a MERN app in a VPS type OVH?

Tags: http, deployment, server, vps, mern

I really need your help today !!

I built a MERN application : everything is running on my local computer (with "npm start server.js" and "npm start index.js" for the client side).

Now, I want to deploy it to my own VPS and I need your help ! I tried so many configurations on internet and nothing is working...

I don't even now where to start again to make it work.

Can someone help me understand :

1. Where do I need to upload my files (client and server) in my vps ?
   [I know that the var/www/html folder need to have an "index.html" but is it the one after running "yarn build" in the client side ?]
2. What commands should I execute to run the server and client side at the same time
3. How should I use npm2 to make it running on internet even if my ssh connection to the vps is closed

Thank you in advance for your help !

Ps : I know that there is a lot of tutorials on internet but I am still struggling after 3 days of research and testing...

Have a nice day,
Alexia

Comment: Ya, It happens. May be you are searching on the internet "Please help me" or "Thank you"  or "I need your help" and you are not getting the correct answer. I would suggest you to start your research by these words. "Deploy app in a VPS of different type."

Comment: Thank you for your help but I already checked this ...